# Finding all items in column1 that matches "DATE" in column2 throught the years

Tags: sql, excel

I would like to write a select statement where the output will return all the records that both (or more?) matches the date dd.mm (with an error margin of +5 days and -5 days from a specific date)
I mean date dd.mm with 5+- days difference, so records from past years but what they got in common is the similar dd.mm
the main condition is that both persons must match the dates more than one year for example in 2018 and 2019

to better imagine this situation we can assume that this is logging records and I would like to find out which 2 persons logged in in nearly the same date (with that 5+- days difference) in last years

example:
TABLE

```
id  person  date
1   John    01.12.2019
2   Mike    01.12.2019
3   Bruce   02.11.2019
4   Lee     02.11.2019
5   John    03.05.2018
......................
......................
556 Mike    03.05.2018
557 Bruce   02.11.2017
558 Lee     01.11.2017
559 John    01.12.2017
```

RESULTS I WANT

```
id  person  date
3   Bruce   02.11.2019
4   Lee     02.11.2019
......................
......................
557 Bruce   02.11.2017
558 Lee     01.11.2017
```

thanks to that return i will be able to see a pattern which names done some action in similar time in the past.

[possible return of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5T7K.png)

Comment: I don't understand what this means: `return all the records that both (or more?) matches the date` Matches **what** date? Your example results return two different dates two years apart. What is the logic to get to your desired results?

Comment: @JNevill i meant date dd.mm with 5+- days difference, so records from past years but what they got in common is the similar dd.mm

Comment: @JNevill to better imagine this situation we can assume that this is logging records and I would like to find out which 2 persons logged in in nearly the same date (with that 5+- days difference) in last years